# Calculation of image offsets for performing cropping

Tags: java, algorithm, image, awt

I am using the `java.awt.Rectangle` class to construct subsets of a GEOTIFF file. In order to do this I would need to specify the x,y offsets, height and width of each subset image. In my particular case I would need to crop the original GEOTIFF image bottom to top. The `java.awt.Rectangle` class specifies that the origin point is to be found in the upper left hand corner.

Please let me know if the calculation of the image offsets are correct and/or there is a better way of calculating the image offsets. The `crop(r`) method is a proprietary method used to crop subsets of the original image.

```
int width = 40;
int height = 34;
int cellSize = 3600;
int xOffset = 0;
int yOffset = 0;
int pixelWidth = cellSize * width;
int pixelHeight = cellSize * height;
for (int i = 0 ; i < width; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < height; j++)
    {
        yOffset = pixelHeight - cellSize *(j+1) ;
        Rectangle r = new Rectangle(xOffset,
                                    yOffset,
                                    cellSize,
                                    cellSize);
        crop(r);
    }
    xOffset = pixelWidth - cellSize * (i+1);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> int width = 40;
> int height = 34;
> int cellSize = 3600;
> int xOffset = 0;
> int yOffset = 0;
> int pixelWidth = cellSize * width;
> int pixelHeight = cellSize * height;
> ```

I would find this easier to follow in a different order:

```
final int CELL_SIZE = 3600;

final int WIDTH = 40;
final int HEIGHT = 34;

final int PIXEL_WIDTH = CELL_SIZE * WIDTH;
final int PIXEL_HEIGHT = CELL_SIZE * HEIGHT;

int xOffset = 0;
int yOffset = 0;
```

Now  I see a natural progression of values and have the variables separate from the constants.  The variables are also closest to where they are changed.

I changed the values that never change to `final` to reflect that.

The ALL_CAPS notation is common for constants.

> ```
> for (int i = 0 ; i < width; i++)
>     {
>     for (int j = 0; j < height; j++)
>         {
>         yOffset = pixelHeight - cellSize *(j+1) ;
>         Rectangle r = new Rectangle(xOffset,
>                                     yOffset,
>                                     cellSize,
>                                     cellSize);
>         crop(r);
>         }
>       xOffset = pixelWidth - cellSize * (i+1);
>      }
> ```

You can write this as

```
for (int xOffset = PIXEL_WIDTH - CELL_SIZE; xOffset >= 0; xOffset -= CELL_SIZE)
{
    for (int yOffset = PIXEL_HEIGHT - CELL_SIZE; yOffset >= 0; yOffset -= CELL_SIZE)
    {
        Rectangle r = new Rectangle(xOffset,
                                    yOffset,
                                    CELL_SIZE,
                                    CELL_SIZE);
        crop(r);
    }
}
```

Then you don't need `i` or `j` at all and you don't have to calculate the offsets further.

I also changed the indent of the brackets to match the more common practice of lining up with the `for` declarations rather than the block contents.

You may want to do this in the other order:

```
for (int xOffset = 0; xOffset < PIXEL_WIDTH; xOffset += CELL_SIZE)
{
    for (int yOffset = 0; yOffset < PIXEL_HEIGHT; yOffset += CELL_SIZE)
    {
```

As that is easier to read.  Not sure how much order matters.

If you need the original order exactly, you may need an extra loop.  The original order started with an `xOffset` of 0 and then went to `PIXEL_WIDTH - CELL_SIZE`.

If you are committed to the `i` and `j` method, consider starting them at 1, as so

```
for (int i = 1 ; i <= width; i++)
    {
    for (int j = 1; j <= height; j++)
        {
        yOffset = pixelHeight - cellSize * j;
```

Then you don't have to add 1 to `i` and `j` each time.

Comment: great code review. Very much appreciated. Now my code is upto standards !

Comment: If I am committed to the i and j method and I don't  start at 0 I do not get the correct total number of subsets. Total number of subsets = 40 * 34 = 1360.

Comment: The last rectangle(going from bottom to top) should have x and y coordinates as 0,0

Comment: @gansub  You have to make all three changes to switch from 0 to 1.  0 becomes 1, `<` becomes `<=`, `(i+1)` becomes `i`.  If you skip the second change in both loops, it will only do `39 * 33` subimages.  In the original code, you should calculate the `xOffset` before the `j` loop rather than after if you want to do 0,0 last.  The first version that I wrote should end with 0,0.

Comment: great thanks ! Much appreciated. I look forward to reading more of your answers !